# Help menu button disappear with delay on mobile devices

Tags: bug, top-bar, design

Something quite annoying has started about a week ago.

The question mark at the top right when using mobile device on full page (not mobile page) comes and goes on the main page, but not on Meta page.

I don't care much about the question mark, what bothers me is that everything loads up and I try to push "messages" then the question mark disappear and everything moves to the right and I push my profile picture.

**On Meta**
[image]

**On normal page**
[image]